# How to get focus node for ie

Tags: javascript

I have a div, I want to find the current focus node(element) in div for ie. For firefox and chrome i got the focus node using selection attribute. There is no this kind of attribute for ie.

> selection.focusNode

pls give your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
document.activeElement
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rRJuZ/1/)**

Comment: This originated in IE but is also supported in recent versions of other browsers.